# When to use $this->data vs $this->request->data

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I've tried Googling this and I can't really find a definitive answer to this question.

I know that when I want to manipulate my data, I'll need to use $this->request->data, but even so, even without manipulation I see that the blog tutorial of the Cakephp 2.0 website, which can be found here:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/part-two.html

Uses $this->request->data. Now, if it's good practice to use $this->request->data even when you're not manipulating your data, what is the use of $this->data within a controller?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$this->data` is deprecated. It still works so that migration will not break. But it will eventually be removed and everything is moving to the CakeRequest and CakeResponse objects.

Go here:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html

And look for:

```
Controller::$data
```

Comment: Whomever down-voted my answer, will you please leave me feedback so I know what needs to be fixed?